# Should I use glkit or cocos3d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, glkit, cocos3d

I'm ready to write my second app using 3D.  The first app was completed in April of 2011.  I want to write another, and have been researching the best route to take.  I used opengl-es last time, and it was tough, but I got through it and the app is pretty sophisticated 3D wise.

This time, I'm looking at glkit and see that this would limit devices to those with IOS 5.  Not sure what other pros/cons there are to using glkit.  Cocos3d would work as well, but I can't really find anyone comparing the two functionality-wise.

I'll be creating my 3D mesh using modo, but I can use Max or Maya as well.  From the 3D app I'll  export a collada file and then convert this to a POD.  The app will allow users to rotate the model, and select (tap) different parts of it in order to change the color of that 3D part.

Can anyone compare and contrast these two technologies, or let me know if I'm on the right track?

Comment: both use opengl anyway, but cocos will give you more options since its a well developed framework, glkit is just meant to ease the transition between opengl es 1 and 2 since it only contains functions that were done for the fixed pipeline, and some to not include so much boiler plate code. My suggestion, use pure opengl es 2 or cocos.

Comment: Neither. For "sophisticated" (whatever that means) 3D apps I'd definitely look into something that provides the right tools to build a 3D app (or world). Check out Unity, Unreal, SIO2.